# Get Metal drawing context in Qt 6

Tags: c++, qt, qt6, qopenglfunctions

When using the Qt OpenGL back-end then it is possible to render custom OpenGL code during Qml scenegraph rendering using the `QQuickWindow::beforeRenderPassRecording` signal, as described in the Qt documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-openglunderqml-example.html

Is a similar functionality available for the Apple Metal back-end? How can I use native Metal code in the scene graph?

Comment: Hyndrix, did you figure out how to get the context in Qt 6?

Comment: The MetalAngle project has an example: https://github.com/kakashidinho/metalangle